# Spring - get a different bean based on context

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a singleton bean that holds a registry of key -> value pairs. The key can change per Http request, and the value is used in dependency injection in a lot of places. I've made a request scoped bean that can return the appropriate value for any method called from within an Http request, as you would expect.

However, there is a new requirement that there is a background thread operating on the key value pairs - think running some callback on a timer. This of course has no access to the Http request, but it *does* have access to the value of the key.

Is there a way to set up a bean definition that will be aware of whether the code is request, and in that case run the existing method, or if it is not in the request scope, run some other way of getting the value.

This an example of the request scoped bean. The code is in Kotlin. The registry parameter is a singleton bean.

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Bean
fun getValue(request: HttpServletRequest, registry: ValueRegistry): Value {
    val id = request.getSession(false).getAttribute(REGISTRY_ID) as String
    return registry.get(id)
}
```

So I would like another bean that can step in in the event that the request is not available.

```
@Scope(value = "singleton")
@Bean
fun getValue2(request: HttpServletRequest, registry: ValueRegistry): Value {
    return registry.first() ?: Value()
}
```

Comment: You could use `RequestContextHolder`, or simply inject the request session bean into the singleton bean. Accessing the request-scoped bean should return a proxy or `null` if the request scope is not available

Comment: I ended up implementing a version of RequestFacade that just had the overrides I needed, and then adding it to RequestContextHolder. It felt very dirty though.